# Python: Setting Ticks in Pandas

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and don't know how to set the xticks.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#Data Read-In
freq = pd.read_csv('Netzfrequenz_Sekundenwerte_2012_KW37.csv', sep=';')
freq.set_index('Datum und Zeit UCT', inplace = True)

#Dataframe sum single values
sums = pd.DataFrame({'Counter': freq['Netzfrequenz in Hz'].value_counts()})
sums['Frequency'] = sums.index
sums = sums.sort_values(by='Frequency')

#plot
sums_plot = sums.plot(x='Frequency', y='Counter', kind='bar', figsize=(12, 9))
sums_plot.set_title('Frequency Distribution KW37 2012 Germany')

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRXiq.png)

It shows way too many xticks. How can I set it to show only a few? Also, can I force a value (e.g. 50) to be exactly in the middle of the x axes?

Any other recommendations are appreciated aswell :)

Greetings and thanks,

Kilian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I can't test this modified solution unless you add sample data, so here is an example where I mock up some data. You clarified that you're getting hung up on `kind=bar` but remember that `pd.DataFrame.plot` returns a `plt.AxesSubplot` object anyhow.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


#Dataframe sum single values
sums = pd.DataFrame({'Counter': [c+213 for c in range(100)]})
sums['Frequency'] = sums.index
sums = sums.sort_values(by='Frequency')

#plot
sums_plot = sums.plot(x='Frequency', y='Counter', kind='bar', figsize=(12, 9),
                     )
sums_plot.set_xticks([0, 25, 50, 75, 100])
sums_plot.set_xticklabels(["Bottom", "Low", "Middle", "High", "Top"])


plt.show()
```

As you can see, the `set_` methods you're familiar with from working with matplotlib `ax` objects are still available. `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` worked on mocked data as shown below.

[image: Solution on mocked data]

---

<del>You have some options but one simple solution is to use `xticks` as an argument of `plot`.</del>

```
sums_plot = sums.plot(x='Frequency', y='Counter', kind='bar', figsize=(12, 9), 
    xticks=[x*0.1 for x in range(490, 451)])
```

<del>Here I assign the sequence `[49, 49.1, ...]` because I can't read what notation the messed up ticks are in your image. You could just manually set the ticks by writing a sequence yourself (e.g. `[49.0, 49.3, 49.6, 50.0]`).</del>

Comment: Hey Charles, thank you for your feedback. Yes I used that before. Unfortunately it does not work with `kind='bar'`. Without it works fine.

Comment: @KilianHelfenbein thanks for clarifying, I have made extensive edits to my answer which hopefully help